# Why split up data retrieved from a database into multiple endpoints, if we need ALL the data anyway?

Tags: database, rest, api-design

I have a "Games" API which retrieves video game data from a large database.
The */games* endpoint returns some very basic information about the game, such as the title, description, etc.

More detailed information, such as the developer, is actually not given by this endpoint. Instead, a reference ID, to be used for another endpoint, is returned.

Example:

```
{
    "id": 01,
    "name": "Pokemon Red"
    "developer(s)": [
                    100131
    ]
}
```

Now, if we want to know the developer(s) of this game, we need to use another endpoint, such as "/developers" with the relevant ID, to actually know who the developer of this game is, and there are many other pieces of information split off like this in this API.

What is the point of splitting off the data into many different endpoints if we eventually need to display all the relevant information to the end customer anyway? Wouldn't it be simpler to just have the */games* endpoint return all the necessary information upfront?

Comment: GraphQL is designed to solve this very problem. `Wouldn't it be simpler to just have the /games endpoint return all the necessary info upfront?` Not really. What if you don't need all the info? What if you want to see other games by the same developers? Should the endpoint provide these aswell? At some point you'll find yourself just returning your whole database.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how GraphQL solves this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your assumption that you always need all the data is typically false. At least at the given time. You may have such a need with your game example, but it seems that even these API developers think differently, judging from how it was designed.

Typically, at time X, you will only need some data, say DX, and then at time Y some data say DY. Now you may load everything up front, but maybe you will never reach time Y?

So there's a trade-off. How big is DY actually? Is it worth loading it, even if I won't ever use it? Because loading data takes time. And memory. And sometimes even CPU (parsing, and some transformations). And there's a security risk involved as well: should we really serve all the data to user, including sensitive data?

Think about a bank serving your account information. Why would it serve your account history up front if you may actually never want to see it? And that might be lots of data. Lots of sensitive data by the way.

Another example: consider Gmail, or any email service. Do you really think it should serve all emails, with all contents, including attachments up front? For those emails from ten years ago as well? With my account, I would probably wait ten years for it to finish loading. In fact, those email services will try to stop you from doing such a thing. Because it would kill their side as well.

And your example fits this pattern quite well, I think. Are you sure that information about a game developer is always relevant to everyone? It sounds unlikely.

Another reason is that if the data dynamically changes you may want to actually call the server and retrieve the most recent piece of information. So back to the bank account. I log in and the server sends me the entire history for some reason. Ok. But in the meantime someone sends me money. Of course I need to call the server again to retrieve that information. Or maybe the server pushes it to me. Either way, some additional communication is needed.

But you are also somewhat correct. Some people will combine lots of various data into single calls. That is especially useful on startup. But requires careful consideration and design. Because you may want to load as much as possible, but not more. How can you find this balance? It is a hard question, for another time maybe.

But eventually you will need to load some data again anyway. And you rarely want to load everything each time.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to have multiple generic endpoints which can be combined to produce a variety of different results.

So for example, say you include the developer list in the Game object as you suggest, but have a page which lists games with just the title. You would be retrieving lots of duplicate information that you wouldn't use.

Similarly, if you wanted to list all the developers, you would have to get all the games and then work out a distinct list of developers across them. Very inefficient.

By splitting the endpoints and only including the IDs, you allow different apps to retrieve the information they need and assemble it as required. This decouples the presentation layer from your API layer.

There is also a more academic argument to be made about your choice of objects, aggregate roots, domains etc

Say we Have the Game object:

```
Game
{
  id
  title
  developerIds[]
  releaseDate
  price
}
```

Do we want to add a second version of this object which fit our page better? We might have

```
GameForLists
{
   id
   title
}


GameWithReviews
{
  id
  title
  reviews[]
}

GameWithDevelopers
{
  id
  title
  developers[]
}
```

Soon we have dozens of such objects, all representing a Game, endpoints which fetch data about games get duplicates which return different game `ViewModels` We find it hard to pass data from one control to another, say I have my list of `GameForLists` but now i want to click on it and show the release date, I have to make another call and get a `Game`. If I have a method `CalculateGameOffer` does it take a Game as a parameter or a GameWithReviews?

It's better to decide on what your objects are at the start and stick with them. That way you build up a consistent model of your underlying data which is flexible and can be reused. You can build logic and functionality around this model rather than going back to the beginning each time.

This makes for a faster turn around for features at the presentation layer. You don't have to go back to the database, add a new view, new objects, new api endpoints each time you have a new idea you want to try out.

Comment: You are saying that if I were to have a endpoint that returned EVERYTHING, I would end up with the 2nd example you provided, which is several different objects with different data in each for different uses?

Comment: no... if you return everything then you have the first problem i describe. ie your drop downs take forever to load because you are getting _EVERYTHING_ the second issue is what you get when you try and solve that by adding views. ie "everything" (for this use case)